# Mirrormaker issue with Kerberos + GSSAPI +SASL_PLAINTEXT

Tags: kerberos, sasl, keytab, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to run Mirrormaker on a kerberos enabled cluster that sources from an off-site non-kerberos cluster, and I am getting the following error when starting up mirror maker.

All of my key tabs are verified and valid, my server.properties/producer.properties/consumer.properties are set correctly, and the KDC is also reachable. Firewalls ports are correctly configured. Has anyone encountered this type of error before?

```
Found unsupported keytype (3) for mirrormaker/myhost.org@KAFKA.SECURE
Found unsupported keytype (8) for mirrormaker/myhost.org@KAFKA.SECURE
Found unsupported keytype (25) for mirrormaker/myhost.org@KAFKA.SECURE
Found unsupported keytype (26) for mirrormaker/myhost.org@KAFKA.SECURE
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 16version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply mirrormaker/myhost.org
[2019-08-20 10:51:00,351] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-2] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:561)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:497)
```

This is the first time we are using mirrormaker on a kerberos enabled cluster, so we have no idea what kind of output we should be getting, or how to solve this issue.
Mirrormaker seems extremely fickle when it comes to configurations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi christopher, i am going to do exactly same setup, did you solve the problem and achieved what you described?

Comment: I did! The key was to not use SSL as it caused Kafka to crash catastrophically. I also destroyed/rebuilt the KRB database, re-issued key tab files, and used FQ names in all the config files.